# fractional matching number of projective plane of uniformity $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, matching-theory

I am wondering for a projective plane $P$ of uniformity $k$, what is $\nu^*(H)$, the [fractional matching number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_matching) of $H$?